# jersey org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.close()V

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

i am currently using jersey to build a RESTful API. am trying to upload a file to the server for that am using jersey media multipart. Here is my code..

```
@Path("/test")
public class Tester {

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public Response test(@FormDataParam("file")InputStream file, @FormDataParam("file")FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail){
    return Response.status(406).entity(fileDetail.getName()).
}
```

and everytime i run this i find this error

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] in context with path 
[/com.mygoga.itutor] threw exception 
[org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.close()V] with 
root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.close()V
```

can anyone please help? thanx!!!

Comment: Can you show your dependencies. You have a dependency version conflict

Comment: i am using jersey-media-multipart 2.25.1 and mimepull 1.9

Comment: [Look here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-multipart/2.25.1). mimepull version used in Jersey 2.25.1 is 1.9.6. See if that fixes your problem

Comment: Thanx @peeskillet u just saved my day. bless u

Comment: @peeskillet i am also facing same issue. i have same version off dependency.